# How to dynamically check for library information in posix compliant systems in C++?

Tags: linux, operating-system, posix

I am playing around with Linux to learn some things about operating systems. Currently I want to query the OS for the version of certain libraries (GLFW and GLEW on particular). I want to print the current version or a message if the library is not installed.

Is there a general way to query the OS for the version of an installed library?

Comment: "Is there a general way to query the OS for the version of an installed library?" - no.

Comment: Typically this is dealt with the *build system* and the *installer* on Linux.

Comment: You can look at [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/)

Comment: @Ron call a system function and ask it what version the indicated library is isntalled under. For example system("library --version")
Or soemthing along those lines

Comment: Are you looking for compile-time, install-time or run-time checks?

Comment: @Galik Runtime Checks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is library-specific.  Each library will have its own method (or might have none) to query what version is loaded.

This is different to querying the system to ask what version of a library is installed--that's the wrong way to go about it because the version loaded in your program might be different to what the system has installed (and the system might have multiple runtime versions installed).

In your specific case, you need to call `glfwGetVersion()` for GLFW, and use `GLEW_VERSION` for GLEW.